# How to put time on the x-axis instead of index values and question about ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset I collected with my Raspberry Pi and DHT22 sensor. This CSV file contains the time (1 measurement every minute), the temperature and humidity. After cleaning the data, I wanted to make a figure with two subplots, but I cannot seem to find an answer as to how put the time on the x-axis, instead of the index values. If you want to try it with the dataset, I uploaded it https://github.com/Robertjehh/tempdata'> here .

Also, I want to have ticks every half degree, for which I couldn't find something that helped me.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('2019-09-15.csv', header = None)
data.columns = ['time','temp','hum']

array =[]
for i, row in data.iterrows():
    if row['temp'] <15 or row['hum'] <40 or row['hum'] > 70:
        array.append(i)
for i in array:
    newtemp = (data.iloc[i-4]['temp'] + data.iloc[i+4]['temp'] ) / 2.0
    newhum = (data.iloc[i-4]['hum'] + data.iloc[i+4]['hum']) / 2.0
    data.at[i, 'temp'] = newtemp
    data.at[i,'hum'] = newhum

x = data.index.values
y1 = data.temp.rolling(window=20).mean()
y2 = data.hum.rolling(window=20).mean()

plt.figure()
f, axes = plt.subplots(2,1)
axes[0].plot(x,y1)
axes[0].set_ylabel('Temperature ($^\circ$C)')
axes[1].plot(x,y2)
axes[1].set_ylabel('Humidity (%)')
```

Changing the data that is used for the x-axis to the time-values does nothing, it puts Jupyter into an infinite loop it seems. This happens after the plt.figure()

By the way, if you have a better way of cleaning the data, you're welcome to share. This is just the first thing that came to mind.

Edit:
I changed the last part of the code,

```py
data.set_index('time', inplace=True)
x = data.index.values
y1 = data.temp.rolling(window=20).mean()
y2 = data.hum.rolling(window=20).mean()
data.plot()
```

Using this code I get one figure, but the piece of "original code", starting with plt.figure(), doesn't work yet, been getting these black bars below the x-axis.

[image: Test plot]

Comment: You will need to use the time column of your dataframe instead of the index when plotting.

Comment: Second to last paragraph, been there ,done that, doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: In that case your question is really about that infinite loop. For that matter one will need to see a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: I have supplied the original post with an edit, please check that out

Comment: This looks like the dates are note correctly converted and stay strings.

Comment: I see that, but data.plot() does actually show the time in intervals of 3 hours and 20 minutes.